# New Element Not Adding to JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The array is something like:

```js
var students = [
  {
    classes: [ 60757198250eab6930e73c01, 607572d41134b063103aba99 ],       
    _id: 604ede883a1fa43120dad097,
    name: 'Ravi Keshri',
    username: '2019ca44',
    password: '$2a$10$h0BAsOLKH92G1Vl1WNCSL.fvX22xyo1.Eeck792HtD0uCJPcvfv/q',
    email: 'ravikeshri.rk1@gmail.com',
    isTeacher: false,
    stream: 'btech',
    department: 'ee',
    phone: '9999999999',
    __v: 12
  }
]
```

I want to add a new property "attendance" to these objects.

```js
User.find().where('_id').in(studentsIds).exec((err, students) => {
  if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.redirect('/teacher/dashboard');
  } else {

      students.forEach(function(student){
          var found = cls.students.find(function(val){return student._id.equals(val.id)});
          var attNum = found.attendance.length;
          var attDeno = cls.dates.length;
          var att = 0;

          if(attDeno != 0) att = (attNum / attDeno)*100;
          
          console.log(student);
          
          // =============================================
          // this is the part where I am facing this issue
          
          // student.attendance = att;
          // student["attendance"] = att;
          // none of the above working
          
          // =============================================
          
          console.log(student);
      });

      console.log(students);
      res.render("teacher/class", { students: students, cls: cls, teacher: teacher, user: req.user });
  }
 });
```

I saw many articles and tried

```
obj.property = value;
obj["property"] = value;
```

Even I tried Array.map to add a new field but its not working. No error coming. Don't know what I am missing. Please help me out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: You can start by removing `User.find().where('_id').in(studentsIds).exec((err, students) => {
  if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.redirect('/teacher/dashboard');
  } else {
` which is not relevant to your question

Comment: Then `cls.students.find(function(val){return student._id.equals(val.id)});` what is the point? You do not have an id in student and you do not have `attendance` either

Comment: Sorry for those lines. Those lines refer to some data not written here. Nevermined I got the solution. Thanks for your time.